# Excel and CSV is converting my telephone number to not have +

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have tried several tricks and none of them are working I have telephone numbers `+4 55 555 555 555` and in Excel the cells that have the little green triangle warning sign, they loose the `+4` and then have no `+4` just a number when exported to CSV. I am exporting to CSV Uni-code 08.

I have tried:

- Formatting to text.
- Formatting to text 0000000000000 thing that someone said.
- Closing and opening excel and then changing file to .txt, then opening file through Open and choosing options for "text" for the number fields.

Ideas?

Comment: In "Format Cells" dialog, choose "Custom" and type `+4 00 000 000`. +4 would be prefixed automatically for that cell.

Comment: And if i have multiple beginnings +4 +1 +27? and multiple lengths?

Comment: Another way is to type the complete phone numbers in column A without the plus symbol, and display them with + symbol in Column B. Example: in B1 type `="+"&A1`

Comment: And, formatting the cells/column as text works fine here, with a warning of course, which can be ignored.

Comment: hmm.. I have a doc with 4000 rows with tel no in two columns, and I need to get it out ;/ not type it in

Comment: Libre Office seems to manage csv and uni-code 8 much better not sure why or how it is not happy with it in excell to csv, but this seems to be working. will try to import to sql and see if it comes through right.

Comment: [su] duplicate: [force entering proper format phone phone number in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12745966)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ALL for help!

but I did try a lot of tricks to try resolve, too many cells were differently formatted, some had plus some did not.

How I resolved this was I used LibreOffice. Its free and it just worked out the box and left my numbers to be right. Was actually better as it just bypassed everything and made sure each time I saved I was really getting Uni-code 08, which is what I needed to import in WordPress.

I also tried Google sheets, but it crashed as my sheet was very large. Did test numbers and it also muddled them up.

The only issue Libre gave me was I had to make a new date format, which was easy to do.

Thanks a mill for all the efforts!